# With React and Jest, how do I mock a Promise I need to await?

Tags: reactjs, promise, mocking, jestjs

I'm using React 16.13.0 and trying to use jest to test if a method was called.  I am very confused about how to use mocks.  I have this method ...

```
class Missions {
    ...
  async removeVolunteerFromMission(missionId: string) {
    const missions = this.repo();
    const mission = await missions.findById(missionId);
    mission.volunteerId = '';
    mission.status = MissionStatus.unassigned;
    return this.repo().update(mission);
  }
...
export default new Missions();
```

How do I test if my "findById" method was called?  I have this test method ...

```
it('unassigns volunteer', async() => {

  const missionId = "1234";
  const mission = new Mission();
  mission.missionId = missionId;

  const mockFindById = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(mission);
  const mockUpdate = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(mission);
  const baseRepo = {
    findById: () => mockFindById,
    update: () => mockUpdate
  };
  jest.spyOn(missions, 'repo').mockReturnValue(baseRepo);

  await missions.removeVolunteerFromMission(missionId);

  console.log("mission === " + mission);

  expect(mockFindById).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

but this fails with

```
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(expected)

Expected number of calls: 1
Received number of calls: 0

  29 |       console.log("mission === " + mission);
  30 | 
> 31 |       expect(mockFindById).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
     |                            ^
```

How do I very that this was actually called?

Comment: what happens in `this.repo()`? much easier(and more reliable) to mock 3rd party module than mock instance method

Comment: `findById: mockFindById`

Comment: Ha, I should have been more confident... just wasn't sure exactly how to articulate what was the issue. Added as answer with brief explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the spies/mocks aren't actually being invoked, the anonymous function is

```
const baseRepo = {
  findById: () => mockFindById,
  update: () => mockUpdate
};
```

but simply setting the mock function will work

```
const baseRepo = {
  findById: mockFindById,
  update: mockUpdate
};
```